# I get 'connection reset by peer' error when I use django to upload file

Tags: python, django, linux

I use the django framework to implement the function of uploading files, the local test is normal, and the following errors occur after deploying to the server.
My code is as follows

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file_obj111 = request.FILES.get('file111')
    f = open('/home/file_loca/' + file_obj111.name, 'wb')
    for chunk in file_obj111.chunks():
        f.write(chunk)
    f.close()
```

It runs normally when tested locally.When I deployed to the server, an internal error appeared.

> [22/Jul/2021 17:26:20] "POST /api/analysis/fuzzy_query HTTP/1.1" 200 15 qqq Internal Server Error: /api/analysis/fuzzy_query Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 391, in read
> return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 40, in read
> result = self.buffer + self._read_limited(size - len(self.buffer))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 28, in _read_limited
> result = self.stream.read(size)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 40, in read
> result = self.buffer + self._read_limited(size - len(self.buffer))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 28, in _read_limited
> result = self.stream.read(size)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b) ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer*